# PowerBI - Is there possible to have 2 dropdown values that are applied to the entire column?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, m

I want to implement on PowerBI a calculator that I developed in Excel.

Basically, it works this way:

1. I have a list of Dates:

[image]

2. I have a Database that combines in a key the name of the source with a date:

[image]

3. I have a calculation table where I apply into a Dropdown menu value an entire column, it combines with the Source, forming a key, where I can calculate the Source variation choosing two dates (an initial and an end date).

[image]

I would like to know how can I apply it into Power Bi, specially step 3. With a Dropdown menu that is applied to an entire column "dynamically"

Comment: You can create a column with a key value and use it as slicer or combination of slicer and measure that receive the value/values as a kind of argument

Comment: Thank you, how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Calculation Groups. To use them, you have to use the free external tool [Tabular Editor](https://www.sqlbi.com/tools/tabular-editor/).

Setting dynamic date ranges like this is a very common use for Calculation Groups.

Here's an example of a prior year Calculation Item:

CALCULATE(SELECTEDMEASURE(), SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR(cal[date]))

You can create multiple Calculation Items to define all the various periods you need.

You can then set the calculation group as the field for a dropdown menu, and each calculation item you defined will be an option in the menu.

Here's an [intro article](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/introducing-calculation-groups/). This same website has the best training on calculation groups you can find online. (And it's all free.)